# limiting of strings or numbers in text boxes Java android

Tags: java, android

How to limit or restrict the words or numbers in the EditText boxes in android Java?

Comment: i think number of characters. correct ??

Comment: i think ur asking about edit text?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `android:maxLength="8"`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="8">
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to put following line in your xml file with the other EditText Lines.

```
android:maxLength="10"
```